# Scrolling Text View

Tags: android

I have a `TextView` inside of a `ViewGroup`.  The text displayed in the `TextView` extends past the width of the `ViewGroup` and is clipped as expected.

What I'm trying to do, is scroll the `TextView` to the left to display the text, and stop when  the end of the text is visible.

However, if I use a `TranslationAnimation`, the `TextView` is "translated" to the appropriate position, but the `TextView` remains clipped where it was in its original position, and I can't find a way around this, other than to follow a similar pattern as used for the marquee in `TextView`.

I also don't see a way to specify in the marquee object, to stop just when the text is just visible, so I think I may need to create my own marquee functionality.

Do I have any other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just wrap your `TextView` with a horizontally-scrolling `ScrollView`?

Normally the `TextView` simply gets clipped due to running out of screen. A `ScrollView` should ensure you can scroll to the portion off screen which was previously clipped.